# jqueryMobile :- How to provide proper spacing between the contents of a listview?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Here my .html file:-

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="productList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">               
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my .js code :-

```
var respPrice = {"Value":[{"ID":"1","productID":"10","subsID":"9","MinPrice":"500","MaxPrice":"50000","Subs":"xyz1"},
                         {"ID":"2","productID":"10","subsID":"9","MinPrice":"9020","MaxPrice":"90020","Subs":"xyz12345"}]}

$.each(respPrice.Value, function(index, value) {
      if(respPrice.length == 0) {
         alert('No product subs list found');
      } else {

       subsId = value.subsID;
       substance = value.Subs;
       minPrice = value.MinPrice;
       maxPrice = value.MaxPrice;        
      $respPrice = '<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child ui-btn-up-e">' + substance + minPrice + '-' + maxPrice + '</li>';

       $('#productList').append($respPrice);
     }               
 });

 $('#productList').listview('refresh');
```

Here is the result:-

[image]

unable to provide proper distance between the "Subs" and "MinPrice-MaxPrice".
Any Help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: remove the classes of `li` in your code.

Comment: if i remove the class of li in my code neither it would take the proper style of list nor the spacing works...any other idea...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FFRrr/ check this. add `data-theme="e" to `ul`. if you want them to work as links, you need to change your code to `<li><a href=">Link</a></li>`

Comment: thanx @Omar for ur responses but i was asking smthing else there. I was asking about the spacing between the contents like: "xyz1  500-50000" and again "xyz12345  5020-50020"...hope you will get me this tym and provide me some solution to this.

Comment: check the same link http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FFRrr/

Comment: @Omar you are just including a space between them but i was asking about the proper spacing such that substance name and the price range should be properly aligned.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/FFRrr/

Comment: best thing to do is to go to jquery mobile site, check out their samples, find listview, then inspect that in chrome dev tools, find the proper class names and then modify those in your css

Comment: thanx Omar....U did it for me...

Comment: You're welcome :) I used JQM grids, and some CSS adjustments.